# How to Access Data from One Class in multiple Children Classes

Tags: php, oop

I'm having a bit of trouble in designing my classes in php.
As you can see in my Code, i want to have one Class instance and having more classes as children which "talk" from one to another. im getting the logged user and get all his information stored to a variable. In my other Classes i recently need to get this UserData.
Any help and Ideas are welcome :)

```
class Factory
{
    private $UserData;

    public function Factory()
    {
        DB::connect();
        $this->getLoggedUserData( $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] );
    }

    private function getLoggedUserData( $user )
    {
        $result = DB::query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' LIMIT 1" );
        $this->UserData =  $result->fetch_assoc();                          
    }

    public function getMyTasks()
    {
        // how to call that class, without instancing it over and over again
        MyOtherClass -> getMyTasks();
    }
}

class MyOtherClass
{
    public function getMyTasks()
    {
        // how to access the "global" variable
        $result = DB::query( "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE userID=" . $UserData['userID'] . " LIMIT 1" );

        // doSomething ($result);
    }

}

class DB 
{
    private static $mysqli; 

    public static function connect()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DB);
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->conect_errno . ')' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');
        self::$mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public static function query( $query )
    {
        $result = self::$mysqli->query( $query );

        if ( self::$mysqli->error ) {
            error_log("QUERY ERROR: " . self::$mysqli->error);
            error_log("QUERY: " . $query);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$Factory = new Factory();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just do `class MyOtherClass extends Factory` then instead of calling getMyTasks inside your factory you call MyOtherClass instead and move your DB connection stuff into the constructor of Factory

Comment: i first thougt about that too, but how/where to instance MyOtherClass then? Or is it a good practise to instance it when i need it? as i will call a lot of methods from MyOtherClass.

Comment: you would only instance myotherclass since that extends factory and factory calls DB so just doing new myotherclass then using myotherclass->getMyTasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here goes a simple trivial approach to your problem

Mind you, this is not complete. Gimme some feedback if this is closing in on what you'd expect

#### your classes changed a bit

```
<?php
class Factory {
  private $UserData;
  private $UserTask;
  public function Factory() {
      DB::connect();
      $this->getLoggedUserData($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']);
  }
  private function getLoggedUserData($user) {
      $result = DB::query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user="'.$user.'" LIMIT 1');
      $this->UserData = $result->fetch_assoc();
  }
  public function getMyTasks() {
    // how to call that class, without instancing it over and over again
    if (!isset($this->UserTask)) $this->UserTask = new MyOtherClass($this->UserData);
    return $this->UserTask->getMyTasks();
  }
}
class MyOtherClass {
  private $UserData;
  public function __construct($userData) {
    $this->userData = $userData;
  }
  public function getMyTasks() {
    // how to access the "global" variable
    $task = DB::query('SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE userID='.$this->UserData['userID'].' LIMIT 1');
    return $this->performTask($task);
  }
  public function performTask($task) {/* doSomething(); */}
}
// usage is not complete, waiting for some extra input
$factory = new Factory();
$taskResults = $factory->getMyTasks();
```

Any input on how to improve this is very welcome

### edit following comments

Let's take a look at how you can solve the problem of having to share instances between different "apps" in your code

- the **singleton** approach: an instance is created on the first call, all subsequent calls are passed the **single** instance
- the **registry** pattern: an object created at the start of the script picks up all initialized requirements and stores them. If any "app" needs the basic set of services (it's not standalone), then pass the **registry** `object` to it's initializer/constructor.

I hope I understood your comments well enough, if not feel free to ask and correct me

Comment: sorry wasn't at work at the weekend :) i will look into it, and will give you more input.

Comment: Sure, don't take this at face value. There's a lot of things you can do with setters and it all depends on what your objects are _supposed_ to do. Sometimes you need a bunch of boilerplate code, and sometimes you just wan't to be practical. Sometimes it's better to take your time while you are designing your classes than to spend hours fixing small modifications in many code files

Comment: so i do have different applications, which use a db connection and need the user credentials. one for instance is a calendar, so i draw and get all calendar entries with my calendar class. another class is tasks, where i get/set tasks, and so on. so i want to have them all resonably connected instead of instancing every application for itself.

Comment: you want them all to have a basic set of **shared** "services" (db, user, environment...)? this looks like a registry pattern

Comment: added a bit at the end, if you want me to expand on these ideas, please, feel free to ask

Comment: well thank you, thats a good point with the registry pattern. i will look this up. great help!

Comment: if your issue becomes resolved, then please close this thread by marking someone's answer or by leaving your own answer and marking it for yourself. **NINJA**'ed

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what would be best for you when i dont know more about the scale of your application etc.

Anyway the simplest way is something like this:

```
$otherClass = new MyOtherClass();
$Factory = new Factory($otherClass);
```

**Class Factory**

```
class Factory
{
    private $UserData;
    private someClass;

    public function Factory(&$someClass)
    {
        $this->someClass = $someClass;
        DB::connect();
        $this->getLoggedUserData( $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] );
    }
...
```

**Usage**

```
$this->someClass->getMyTasks();
```

But in case you only want access to the methods/variables of the parent, then yes extend the class.

Comment: i do have about 6 other classes which i don't need instanced at first start. if a user goes to a specific page, i'd instance my needed classes, BUT i might have already instanced some classes, so i wouldnt need to reinstance them.

Comment: maybe you should look into autoloaders, something like: function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

Comment: i've autoloaded the other ones already. i'm now using the registry pattern, which works for what i need to do.